# Location Manager not getting location

Tags: objective-c, cllocationmanager

I am trying to update one of my apps to IOS9 and Xcode 7.2.1. Location Manager works in an earlier version, but is now not working.  No errors or warnings...nothing.  It seems my code is not getting to "didUpdateLocations".  My code is below;

```
- (void)setupViewController {

    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    if ([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAlwaysAuthorization)])
    {
        [self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
    }

    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = 100;
    //locationManager.requestLocation;
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];


    //return coordinate;

    [self performSelector:@selector(stopUpdatingLocation:) withObject:@"Timed Out" afterDelay:5];       

}
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
    NSLog(@"Doesn't get here.");

    self.bestEffortAtLocation = newLocation;
    latitudeString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%g", newLocation.coordinate.latitude];
    longitudeString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%g", newLocation.coordinate.longitude];

There is other code here that gets city, country, etc.
```

No idea at this point what to do.  I've looked for similar problems and not found anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager 
    didUpdateLocations:(CLLocation *)newLocation 
    fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
```

That method will never be called, as it corresponds to no [delegate method](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManagerDelegate_Protocol/index.html). You need to implement this method:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
     didUpdateLocations:(NSArray<CLLocation *> *)locations {
```

Answer (score 1):

Update Your info.plist file.

```
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>This application requires location services to work</string>
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>This application requires location services to work</string>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Like this.

```
- (void)setupViewController
{
    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;
    self.locationManager.distanceFilter = 100;
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer;

    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    self.bestEffortAtLocation = newLocation;
    latitudeString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%g", newLocation.coordinate.latitude];
    longitudeString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%g", newLocation.coordinate.longitude];

    [self.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
}
```

remove your `performselector` method from `setupViewController` and you have to use all the place `self`. Hope it Helps you.